# Laravel 5.3 Increment 001 to 002 in code

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, auto-increment

I have a `registration_id` in format `KUTWJH210117001`. Next time when the user posts the `registration_id` I want to increment it to `KUTWJH210117002`, 
but I'm getting the output as:

```
KUTWJH210117001  // the first time  
KUTWJH2101172    // next time it will be 
KUTWJH2101173    // and so on
```

**The Code**

```
public function setRegistrationIdAttribute($rid)
{
    $getLastRegistrationId = Driver::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->registration_id;
    $getDateToCheck = substr($getLastRegistrationId , 6, 6);

    if($getDateToCheck === date('dmy')) {
        $toIncrement = substr($getLastRegistrationId, -1);
        $increment =  float($toIncrement++);                       //i'm incrementing here
        $this->attributes['registration_id'] = $rid.date('dmy').$increment;
    }
    else 
    {
     $this->attributes['registration_id'] = $rid.date('dmy')."001";
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) to format:

```
$this->attributes['registration_id'] = $rid.date('dmy').sprintf("%03d", $increment);
```

---

`%03d` - tells that you are formatting 3 digit number. So, zero's will be padding automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
$increment = str_pad($increment, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```